# How to save separate output file for each chain_id?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I have below code to print predefined sequence from pdb file. Now I want to save separate output file for each chain_id.

How to save separate output for each chain_id?

Expected Output:

I want to save output file for each chain_id.

If input file name is `1AHI.PDB`, in this file if we have four chain id A, B, C, D, so I want output file: `1AHIA.txt`,  `1AHIB.txt`, `1AHIC.txt`, `1AHID.txt`. This will go for each input file. I have 2000 more input file in my input directory.

Code:

```
from glob import glob

in_loc = r'C:/Users/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/'
out_loc = r'C:/Users/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Final_result/'


def test():
    fnames = glob(in_loc+'*.pdb')

    for each in fnames:
    # This is the new generated file out of input file (.txt).
        formatted_file = each.replace('pdb', 'txt')

        formatted_file = formatted_file.replace(in_loc, out_loc)

    # This is the input file
        in_f = open(each, 'r')

    # A new file to be opened.
        out_f = open(formatted_file, "w")

    # Filtering results from input file
        try:
            out_chain_list = filter_file(in_f)
            for each_line in out_chain_list:
                out_f.write(each_line)

        # Closing all the opened files.
            out_f.close()
            in_f.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception for file: ', each, '\n', e)
            out_f.close()
            in_f.close()


def filter_file(in_f):
    atom_ids = ['C4B', 'O4B', 'C1B', 'C2B', 'C3B']
    chain_ids = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    order = [0, 1, 4, 3, 2]

    previous_chain_id = None
    chain_list = []
    out_chain_list = []

    for line in in_f:

        if line.startswith('HETATM '):
            line = line.replace('HETATM ', 'HETATM')

        if line.startswith('HETATM'):
            line_list = line.split()
            chain_id = line_list[3][0]
            atom_id = line_list[1]

            if atom_id in atom_ids and chain_id in chain_ids:

                if chain_id != previous_chain_id:
                    c_ls = []
                    if chain_list:
                        c_l = chain_list[-5:]
                        c_l = [c_l[i] for i in order]

                        for i in range(5):
                            c_ls += c_l[:4]
                            c_ls.append('\n')
                            c_l = c_l[-4:] + c_l[:1]

                    out_chain_list += c_ls
                    chain_list.append('\n')

                chain_list.append(line)
                previous_chain_id = chain_id

    c_ls = []
    if chain_list:
        c_l = chain_list[-5:]
        c_l = [c_l[i] for i in order]

        for i in range(5):
            c_ls += c_l[:4]
            c_ls.append('\n')
            c_l = c_l[-4:] + c_l[:1]
    out_chain_list += c_ls

    return out_chain_list

test()
```

*** Edited After Ans***

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Test_10.py", line 31, in test
suffix), 'w')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Final_result//C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file\\1A4ZHETATM15207  C4B NAD A 501      47.266 101.038   7.214  1.00 11.48           C  \n.txt'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Test_10.py", line 94, in <module>
test()
  File "C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Test_10.py", line 40, in test
out_f.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'out_f' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: In your list of output files, do you mean "1AHIA.txt,  1AHIB.txt, 1AHIC.txt, 1AHID.txt"? You have 1AHIB.txt twice and 1AHID.txt does not appear.

Comment: Whats the problem in your code ?

Comment: @Shasha99, There is no problem in program. But I want to modify. I have tried to but I have no idea how to get output for each chain_id.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code opens one output for each input file. But you want an output file for each out_chain item and there can be multiple out_chain items in each input file. So you need to open and close your output files in the inner loop where you're processing out_chain items. Here's one way you could do it:

```
def test():
    fnames = glob(in_loc+'*.pdb')

    for each in fnames:
    # This is the new generated file out of input file (.txt).
        formatted_file = each.replace('pdb', 'txt')
        suffix = 'txt'

        formatted_file = formatted_file.replace(in_loc, out_loc)
        ofstem = each.replace('.pdb', '')

    # This is the input file
        in_f = open(each, 'r')

    # A new file to be opened.
        # out_f = open(formatted_file, "w")

    # Filtering results from input file
        try:
            out_chain_list = filter_file(in_f)
            for each_line in out_chain_list:
            # open and write output file for each out_chain item
                out_f = open('{}/{}{}.{}'.format(out_loc, 
                                       ofstem, 
                                       each_line, 
                                       suffix), 'a')
                out_f.write(each_line)
                out_f.close()

        # Closing all the opened files.
            in_f.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception for file: ', each, '\n', e)
            out_f.close()
            in_f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your `filter_file` that you could receive a dictionary with `chain_id` as a key. If you'll have `out_chain_dict` in format `{'chain_id':out_chain_list}` you can easily create a distinct file for each  `chain_id`:

```
def test():
    fnames = glob(in_loc+'*.pdb')

    for each in fnames:
    # This is the path for new generated file.
        path_file = each.replace(in_loc, out_loc)

    # This is the input file and iltering results from input file
        with open(each, 'r') as in_f:
            try:
                out_chain_dict = filter_file(in_f)

            except Exception as e:
                print('Exception for file: ', each, '\n', e)
                continue

            for (chain_id, out_chain_list) in out_chain_dict.items():
                # This is the new generated file out of input file (.txt).
                formatted_file = path_file.replace('.pdb', chain_id + '.txt')

                # A new file to be opened.
                with open(formatted_file, "w") as out_f:
                    for each_line in out_chain_list:
                        out_f.write(each_line)
```

**EDIT** of `filter_file`:

```
def filter_file(in_f):
    atom_ids = ['C4B', 'O4B', 'C1B', 'C2B', 'C3B']
    chain_ids = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    order = [0, 1, 4, 3, 2]

    previous_chain_id = None
    chain_list = []
    out_chain_dict = {}     # Change out_chain_list to dict

    for line in in_f:

        if line.startswith('HETATM '):
            line = line.replace('HETATM ', 'HETATM')

        if line.startswith('HETATM'):
            line_list = line.split()
            chain_id = line_list[3][0]
            atom_id = line_list[1]

            if atom_id in atom_ids and chain_id in chain_ids:

                if chain_id != previous_chain_id:
                    c_ls = []
                    if chain_list:
                        c_l = chain_list[-5:]
                        c_l = [c_l[i] for i in order]

                        for i in range(5):
                            c_ls += c_l[:4]
                            c_ls.append('\n')
                            c_l = c_l[-4:] + c_l[:1]

                    try:                                            # Here add c_ls to an existing key chain_id
                        out_chain_dict[chain_id] += c_ls   #
                    except KeyError:                                # or create new chain_id key
                        out_chain_dict[chain_id] = c_ls    # if it appears at the first time
                    chain_list.append('\n')

                chain_list.append(line)
                previous_chain_id = chain_id

    c_ls = []
    if chain_list:
        c_l = chain_list[-5:]
        c_l = [c_l[i] for i in order]

        for i in range(5):
            c_ls += c_l[:4]
            c_ls.append('\n')
            c_l = c_l[-4:] + c_l[:1]
    # I guess here we add the last chain_id which corresponds to `chain_id` key
    try:
        out_chain_dict[chain_id] += c_ls
    except KeyError:
        out_chain_dict[chain_id] = c_ls

    return out_chain_dict
```

Comment: Error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Test_10.py", line 82, in <module>
    test()
  File "C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Test_10.py", line 22, in test
    for (chain_id, out_chain_list) in out_chain_dict.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: You should modify your `filter_file` to obtain a dictionary as output.

Comment: I am not understand what should I modify?

Comment: In `filter_file` instead of `out_chain_list += c_ls` you should do smth like `try: out_chain_dict[chain_id] += c_ls; except KeyError: out_chain_dict[chain_id] = c_ls`. Then you'll have separate out_chain_lists for each `chain_id`.

Comment: I did but not getting output? can you please edit my code? I am new in python that why unable to understand or fix this problem?

Comment: @Vish I edited the answer in the way I think it should be. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, getting error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Test_10.py", line 90, in <module>
    test()
  File "C:/Users/Vishnu/Documents/NAD/NAD/result/test_result_file/Test_10.py", line 24, in test
    formatted_file = path_file.replace('.pdb', chain_id + '.txt')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`

Comment: @vish I edited: changed `out_chain_dict[previous_chain_id]` to `out_chain_dict[chain_id]`.

Comment: Shkaberd, Now I am getting output but there is some problem. Output of A chain is blank and A chain is chain B file. `1AHIA.txt` is blank and `1AHIB.txt` - here we have A and B chain data? can you please guide me what's the problem?